# How can I use Python macros in Libreoffice calc?

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice-calc, python3

Is it possible use Python macros in Libreoffice calc 6.0.7.3 and Ubuntu 18.04? I meant something like when Calc runs a macro, it would save the data to CSV format, open it in Python, modify the data and save it to the CSV file and then Calc will reload the file.

Comment: Yes, Python-UNO can do things like this. As mentioned in [the other post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563639/how-one-can-use-python-script-in-libreoffice-calc), work through a tutorial such as https://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html to get started. Then if you run into a specific problem, post a question on stackoverflow.com (because it's programming) or [ask.libreoffice.org](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/), currently the most active LO forum.